# how to get an object from a textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the value of a textarea:

```
STORY 01---abc
STORY 02---def
STORY 03---ghi
```

From the above I need an object:

```
{"STORY 01":"abc","STORY 02":"def","STORY 03":"ghi"}
```

My try - without success:

```
let obj = {};
let arr = $('#txa').val().split('\n');
for(el of arr){
  let a = el.split('---')[0];
  let b = el.split('---')[1];
  obj.a = b;
}
```

Result: `a: "ghi"`

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, but instead of dot (`obj.a`) notation, you have to use bracket (`obj[a]`) notation to set the new object keys. Otherwise you are always updating the key `a` of the object.

Also, note there is no need to duplicate the `split()` call, you can do it once and get both values from the resulting array.

```js
let obj = {};
let arr = $('#myTArea').val().split('\n');

for (el of arr)
{
    let [a, b] = el.split('---');
    obj[a] = b;
}

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj["STORY 01"]);
console.log(obj["STORY 02"]);
console.log(obj["STORY 03"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="myTArea">STORY 01---abc
STORY 02---def
STORY 03---ghi</textarea>
```

Comment: Why I'm getting `STORY 01: "abc"` i.e. names without quotes?

Comment: Because the object is a JavaScript object and that's how the specs are. You want JSON which you get when you `stringify` the object with `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: @Mouser, but in the `Shiders's` snippet there is no any `stringify` function?

Comment: Well with my comment you can easily add that yourself.

Comment: @Mouser, of course, thanks but the question is `Why...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Comment: @Mouser, once again - code on my localhost and the code above are absolutelly the same - but my result is without quotes on the object names. Your link doesn't help to find the reason.

Comment: @qadenza I can't figure out what you say (where do you get `keys` without quotes?), I have updated to show how to access particular elements of the created object.

Comment: @Shidersz, I'm getting this - `{STORY 01: "abc", STORY 02: "def", STORY 03: "ghi"}
`

Comment: @qadenza That is rare, that is not a valid `key` identifier for what I have read here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties. Maybe your local environment just output the object that way.

Comment: Again getting JavaScript key values without quotes is perfectly legal and your code is working fine. If you want to have quotes around the key values convert it into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify(obj)`. In that way you can send it to another program. If you are planning to use `obj` in your JavaScript code it will work perfectly!

Comment: @Mouser that's all truth, but that's not my question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a string accessor

```
obj[a] = b
```

`obj.a` referes to the property 'a', `obj[a]` refers to the property with the key equal to the value of a

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

Using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

`.match(/(?!\n).+/g)` To get an array of each line.

For each line, split it with `---` and update the accumolator (`a`) and return it.

```
.reduce((a,c)=>{
   const [key, value] = c.split("---");
   a[key]=value;
   return a;
 }, {});
```

## Solution

```js
const data = `
STORY 01---abc
STORY 02---def
STORY 03---ghi
`;

const res = data.trim()
 .match(/(?!\n).+/g)
 .reduce((a,c)=>{
   const [key, value] = c.split("---");
   a[key]=value;
   return a;
 }, {});

console.log(res);
```

## Recommendation

I would re-organize the final output differently since your key has a space. Also taking input directly from the textarea and using it as a key is prone to user input errors.

```js
const data = `
STORY 01---abc
STORY 02---def
STORY 03---ghi
`;

const res = data.trim()
 .match(/(?!\n).+/g)
 .map(c=>{
   const [key, value] = c.split("---");
   return {key, value};
 });

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @qadenza it's actually pretty standard way of coding using the latest JS features.

Answer (score 1):

The key is in adding properties to the `obj` using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

I used a different approach using `String.prototype.substring` and `Array.prototype.forEach`

```js
//vanilla solution - no jQuery

const obj = {}; //use constant since the variable itself won't change
const arr = document.querySelector("#myTArea").value.split('\n'); //same here
//since arr is the array containing the splitted values
//we can use array's forEach
arr.forEach(function(element){
  const delimiter = element.indexOf("-");
  const keyValue = element.substring(0, delimiter); 
  const value = element.substring(delimiter+3); //delimiter is 3 long, so index+3

  obj[keyValue] = value;
});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<textarea id="myTArea">STORY 01---abc
STORY 02---def
STORY 03---ghi</textarea>
```